# { '__others__': None }

Tags: python

I came across a Python script that contained:

```
{'__others__': None}
```

This was assigned to a variable. I want to know what it does; can someone tell me, or direct me to somewhere where I can learn it myself?

Comment: It creates a dictionary with one key `'__others__'` and `None` as its value. That's all there is...

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of this used in context? A link to where you *"came across"* it? Have you tried *changing* it - what happened?

Comment: Hi, I cannot share any code snippets as it belongs to my employer.I am analysing the code now, will get back as soon as I bring out some meaning out of it.Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

That dictionary has no special meaning in Python. It is *just* a dictionary with a string key and `None` as the value.

Without more context it is impossible to tell why that codebase is using `__others__` as a key, but as long as it remains just a key in a dictionary then it'll never amount to anything more than just another string key.

It is probably a special value chosen not collide with other strong keys to be stored.